# Cannot login using Facebook credentials

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, parse-platform

I signed up user using FacebookSDK and ParseSDK. After that I was trying to log in with the help of 
**logInWithUsernameInBackground** using Facebook credentials of already signed up user.

```
- (IBAction)loginButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSString * login =_emailTextField.text;
    NSString * pas = _passwordTextField.text;

    [PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:login password:pas
                                    block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
                                        if (user) {
                                            MasterViewController *viewController = [self.navigationController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LibraryTableView"];
                                            [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];                                  
                                        } else {
                                             NSLog(@"Wrong log in");

                                        }
                                    }];
}
```

However I get an error

> [Error]: invalid login parameters (Code: 101, Version: 1.7.5)

Could you please help me ?

Comment: You don't login using your facebook username and password.

Comment: Read the docs first: https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-facebook-users